# Python 3.5 - Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I've seen quite a few different issues with "Connection reset by peer" and Python, however, I think this problem is different.

Here's the problem: I am trying to access a web service over https that is in the same network as mine. Every attempt I've made to perform the call through Python has came back with "Connection reset by peer". I am running this on Linux.

However, I can both Curl and access the web service through the browser without any troubles. Also, this same script works on Windows, and other Linux environments (Although those are running Python 2.7).

I have tried both requests and using base urllib.request.

```
# I specify blank proxy since I have CNTLM setup for outbound.
requests.get(url, proxies={'https': ''}, auth=(user, pass), verify=False)
```

I have also tried:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env=False

# This still brings up 'Connection reset by peer' with/without http auth
response = session.get(url)
```

And I have tried the long way...

```
import urrlib
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({})
proxy_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(proxy_opener)

# do the same for basic auth....

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

My current assumption is that the default SSL/TLS protocol is a non-accepted protocol by the servers. Basically means the servers need to get updated to work with the newest versions of TLS.

However, Requests and Urllib were not resolving that connection issue. I had specify an older version of SSL (I know... I know...) to use in the transport.

My code ended up being similar to the below, [which was derived from the requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version)

```
import certifi
import ssl
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

class Ssl3HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        # specify the version of SSL you want to use below
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize, block=block, 
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)

s = requests.Session()

# May or may not need this. I needed it since I didn't need to route through a proxy to get to local services.
s.trust_env = False

s.verify = certifi.where()
s.auth = (user, password)  # Basic-Auth username/password

s.mount(base_url_of_your_service, Ssl3HttpAdapter())

req = s.get(your_service_url)
print(req.text)
```